# Chef using variables in a array

Tags: arrays, ruby, linux, chef-infra, chef-recipe

How can you use variables in an array in Chef. I am trying to create multiple folder with an array. However my code does not work:

Code

```
variable1 = "/var/lib/temp"
variable2 = "/opt/chef/library"

%w{ #{variable1} #{variable2} }.each do |dir| 
    directory dir do
       owner 'root'
       group 'root'
       mode  '755'
       recursive true
       action :create
    end
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `%w{ ... }` syntax is for declaring an array of words, and no interpolation is done. Since you want an array of pre-existing strings, you can do it this way by declaring a plain-old array:

```
[ variable1, variable2 ].each do |dir|
  # ...
end
```

Or you can switch to this:

```
%w[ /var/lib/temp /opt/chef/library ].each |dir|
  # ...
end
```

The second form makes a lot more sense since that's your intent. No need for intermediate variables.

Comment: Thanks for your answar, that worked. How can I set user group with that command on subfolers? `recursive true` doesn't set user group on subfolders below `/var/lib/temp` and `/opt/chef/library`. Equiqvalent command to `chown -R user:group /var/lib/temp/*` in Linux.

Comment: That's a whole other question, so best to split that out as a separate thing.